# CALayer or other technique to actually modify the colors of layers behind, rather like clipping

Tags: ios, uikit, calayer

Summary, in iOS how to have a view that *modifies the pixels of all the views behind it.*

---

Say you have a view, well any views, but let's consider a collection view which happens to just be some color blocks:

[image]

Say we added a view on top, **CleverView**, which either just blocks that view (so, white - trivial) or even "cuts a hole" in that layer (relatively easy to do, google).

No problem so far: so here's CleverView just a white square:

[image]

But what if we want to do this:

[image]

CleverView is changing all the saturation below it,

Or perhaps this:

[image]

CleverView is changing the hue or whatever below it.

Note that in the examples it's working in a pixel-wise fashion, it's not ("just") flagging each collection view cell to change all of the cell color.

So ideally CleverView would do this to anything at all that happens to be behind it (ie, whatever bunch of views it covers or partly covers, hence the collection view example which is just 'many views).

Naturally both the underneath stuff, and the shape of CleverView, can be animating, moving, in real time.

Is there a way this could be done in iOS?

(In that specific example, what I do is just, have two of the collection views: the bottom one and the top one has the new color values.  Simply with care clip the top one to achieve the effect.  But obviously that's not as Clever as a view that actually "modifies the values of all the pixels behind it".)

{Note too that, obviously, you can just make basically a screen shot, munge that image, and show it; not really a great solution.}

Answer (score 1):

The `CALayer` has a property `backgroundFilters` where you could normally add a `CIFilter` that would do the job. But, documentation states that

> Special Considerations This property is not supported on layers in
>   iOS.

That's annoying, but that's all that we have. Probably, it's due to performance considerations.

I would suggest to look into `SceneKit`, there the primitives are very similar to `CoreAnimation`, also animatable with `CAAnimation`, but provide advanced tools to configure and control many more aspects of the rendering.

For example, `SCNNode` has `filters`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407949-filters?language=objc